# Need a better option then ms access

Tags: winforms, ms-access, ado.net, sql-server-express

I have a Access database that I am using for a back-end to my windows form application.

Any good examples for using SQL Express for accessing the datafile so that Office or MS Office Runtime does not need to be installed on a users computer to use the program?

I am currently using ADO.Net but the program still requires

Comment: Have you tried installing this app on a machine without the runtime? You'll probably find that it still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, all recent versions of windows starting from win 2000 onwards ships with all components needed to open and read an access database.

The only reason for installing Access would be if you using reports and forms and parts of the UI.

So, on any recent version of windows you can open and read a Access mdb file without the need to install anything – in fact you can using windows scripting and not have installed even any development tools or even any software beyond the default software on the windows box.

Comment: Actually that would be true for MDB files.   ACCDB files will require the ACE drivers.

Comment: The only other variation would be if they are using some version of Windows Embedded or Windows CE. I highly doubt this is the case based on the OP's question but thought I would mention it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using SQLite?

Comment: I would like to have something that is already distributed with windows already so clients don't need to download or install other components.

Comment: They won't need to - the beauty of Sqlite is that you can embed it in your code!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at scaling up to SQL Express I'd recommend looking at either the Entity Framework or Linq-to-SQL for your data access layer.  (Though both should work fine against your Access database as well.)  Here are some good quick start tutorials for each framework:

Entity Framework Quickstart:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx

ScottGu's Linq-to-SQL tutorial:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Also if you don't want to worry about client installs, you'll need to place your install of SQL Express on a server and use it as a shared database.  If you need a per-client database SQL Express is going to require additional installs on the client.